# Vite + Vitest project getting an import error with '@vaadin/notification'

Tags: vaadin, config, vite, vitest

I have a new Vite project with Svelte and Typescript and I am trying to integrate it with Vitest to start writing unit tests. However when running `npm test` I am getting the following error:

```
FAIL  src/util.test.ts [ src/util.test.ts ]
SyntaxError: Named export 'setCancelSyntheticClickEvents' not found. The requested module '@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/settings.js' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from '@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/settings.js';
const { setCancelSyntheticClickEvents } = pkg;
```

File that is being tested - util.ts:

```
import '@vaadin/notification'

export const sum = (item1: number, item2: number): number => {
    return item1 + item2 
}
```

Unit test file - util.test.ts:

```
import { describe, test, expect } from 'vitest' 
import { sum } from './util'

test('123', () => {
    expect(sum(1, 1)).toBe(2)
})
```

Vitest config - vitest.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'
import commmonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte(), commmonjs()],
  test: {
    globals: true, 
  }
  }
})
```

Package json:

```
{
  "name": "svelte-ts",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "test": "vitest",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "check": "svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.5",
    "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^2.4.2",
    "@tsconfig/svelte": "^5.0.0",
    "@vitest/ui": "^0.34.6",
    "svelte": "^4.0.5",
    "svelte-check": "^3.4.6",
    "tslib": "^2.6.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5",
    "vite-plugin-babel": "^1.1.3",
    "vitest": "^0.34.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vaadin/notification": "^24.2.0"
  }
}
```

I am certain that it is the import for vaadin/notification in the `sum.ts` file because when I comment it out the tests pass.

From the error it seems like there is a conflict between using CommonJS modules and ES6 imports in this @vaadin/notification package.

- I've tried reading parts of the documentation on vite and vitest to set up these configuration files.
- Due to the conflict I've tried adding the CommonJS pluging to the `vitest.config.ts`. I was hoping it would transform the older commonjs module.
- I've also tried adding the `babel` plugin to the `vitest.config.ts` but this didn't change the error

Any suggestions would be appreciated thank you.